# How to Scroll a list to perform an iteration flow of app using appium?

Tags: java, maven, testing, appium

i need to perform a large list of account closing.The list of 200 accounts which is available as a drop down.only 6 accounts will be available on screen at a time ,for others need to scroll down.How can i perform it using Appium scripting. The flow i tried and sample source code i tried is given below

```
package ******;

import java.util.List;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class QuickPay extend ********{  



     @Test
     public void T1a_Landingpage() {

        public void  scroll(int i){
            do{
                size = driver.manage().window().getSize(); //Get the size of screen.
                System.out.println(size);                     
                int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);//Find starty point which is at bottom side of screen.
                int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);  //Find endy point which is at top side of screen.            
                int startx = size.width / 2; //Find horizontal point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen width.     
                System.out.println("starty = " + starty + " ,endy = " + endy + " , startx = " + startx);     // int startx = size.width;
                driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000);//Swipe from Bottom to Top.
                //Thread.sleep(2000);   
                }                                    

                 //AAD Closing starts
                     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-1')]")).sendKeys("1111");
                     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-tab-5')]")).click();                   

                     for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
                         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-18')]")).click();                    
                         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-input-5')]")).click();
                         do{
                             if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-simplelistitem-"+i+"')]")) != null){

                                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-simplelistitem-"+i+"')]")).click();
                                }
                             else{
                                    scroll(i);
                                }i++;
                             }
                         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-simplelistitem-"+i+"')]")).click();                         
                         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-input-6')]")).click();
                         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-simplelistitem-3')]")).click();                     
                         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-30')]")).click();                    
                         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-31')]")).click();                    
                                       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-37') and @index='1']")).click();  
                         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-37') and @index='1']")).click();
                                     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-37') and @index='1']")).click();
                                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-37') and @index='1']")).click();
                                   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-49')]")).click();

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using above 1.5 appium version you can do like below

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    logger.info("size of screen" + size);

    // Find swipe start and end point from screen's with and height.
    // Find startx point which is at right side of screen.
    int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.70);
    // Find endx point which is at left side of screen.
    int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.30);
    // Find vertical point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen
    // height.
    int starty = size.height / 2;
    logger.info("Scrolling down with the coordinates " + "startx = " + startx + " ,endx = " + endx + " , starty = "
            + starty);

    // Scroll down
    driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 3000);
```

Note: The screen size dimensions are for iPad

otherwise if using below 1.6 then you can use JavaScript to scroll

Comment: i already tried the above one, but in my scenario it was not applicable. i need to close first five accounts from the list then i need to scroll down for the next and so and so i need to close 200 accounts

Comment: correct... you use it in for loop the above function , and call the above function to scroll once and scroll until you find the account which you want to close..the above code will scroll only once , you have to write a wrapper above where you call the above code and scroll n times till you find the account id / element identifier

Comment: is there is any sample references or samples to help with my code

Comment: i=0;
do{
 
 element = check whether element is present [e.g. in your case account ] [write a function which check whether give element is present or not]
 if(ele!=null){
  //you got an element so close the account
  break;
 }else{
  scroll() //where scroll is a function having above code 
  i++;
 }
 }while(i<n)
}

Comment: let me know whether it helps you

Comment: i was working on it.  i will update the source code after completing

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would swipe from the first element location on the screen to the 6th element's location on the screen until the first element on the screen is similar to the last iteration as per the below code

```
public boolean removeGroupByName() {
    nameStart = "";
    while (true) {
        doYourLogicOnThe6Elements();
        if (!keepSwippingGroup()) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static String nameStart = "";

private boolean keepSwippingList() {
    if (isElementPresent(By.xpath(FIRST_ELEMENT_XPATH)) && isElementPresent(By.xpath(LAST_ELEMENT_XPATH))) {
        AndroidElement firstElement = (AndroidElement) driver.findElementByXPath(FIRST_ELEMENT_XPATH);
        AndroidElement lastElement= (AndroidElement) driver.findElementByXPath(LAST_ELEMENT_XPATH);
        if (nameStart.equals(firstElement.getText())) {
            return false;
        } else {
            nameStart = firstElement.getText();
            swipe(lastElement.getLocation().x, lastElement.getLocation().y, firstElement.getLocation().x,
                    firstElement.getLocation().y, 2000);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```